# workaround to execue @Certificate([KeyLength];Certificate) on scheduled agent?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a database who retrieved data from Names.nsf

I want to fill a field with the value of the lenght of the public certificate for each person in Domino Directory.
`@Certificate([KeyLength];Certificate)` does the job from the view (agent view) or when the document is opened.

But do not give back a value when used in a scheduled agent:

```
doc.CertificateLength=Evaluate("@Certificate([KeyLength];Certificate)",doc)
```

Do we have workaround to achieve this ?
Unitil I found only solution with uidocument, no backend solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Certificate item has the PROTECTED flag set. You can see it if you look at that item in the fields list on the second tab of the document properties dialog.

That flag indicates that you need Editor access or above to access that field. So the problem is likely that your agent is running under an identity that lacks Editor access. Verify that the signer of the agent has Editor rights in the database's ACL.  Also, open the agent in Domino Designer, and check the runtime security level on the Security properties tab. It may be necessary to set it to level 2 (Allow restricted operations), but I'm not sure about that. In any case, re-sign it with an appropriate ID file if its got your signature and you only have Reader or Author rights.  Come to think of it, if it's your agent, you have Designer rights unless it's a private agent, so maybe it is the runtime security level setting.